# Get last inserted id in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I saw that the function `mysqli_insert_id` can return the last inserted or updated id.

But is it users safe? I mean, if some users at the same time insert or update query fires (on the same `link`) from different locations so it will return correct insert id to appropriate user?

Comment: hi please checkout my answer

Comment: stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqli_insert_id+safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) comment, I saw that `mysqli_insert_id` is multi-user safe. If each user gets `msqli` link, the `mysqli_insert_id` returns the correct id, no metter how many users fires insert queries simultaneity.

Answer (score 0):

yes MySQLi_insert_id() is best i always use this code. that code send true value

Answer (score -1):

Based on user opinions and my experience it's safe but you can always code your application to recheck it.

For example if you have table with fields (id, id_user, data1, data2, ...) and user makes you insert data in this table, you can launch mysqli_insert_id immediately after insert, get the record from table:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE id = $value_from_mysli_insert_id AND id_user = $current_user
```

And now you are sure that this is user's record. Of course you can also get the whole record and recheck if all data is the same as user inserted them into table

Comment: Also, to let you know, beside "opinions" there is such a thing called "official manual".

Comment: There is nothing in official manual http://au2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php telling this function works without any problems in all conditions so users keep asking if this function works in multi user environment

Comment: Well, to find the proper one is not that easy, I have to admit. [here it goes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)